# Loading simple ESRI HTML JavaScript in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, html, internet-explorer

Is there any particular reason this simple ESRI HTML JavaScript won't load in IE11? Chrome works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
          zoom: 13,
          fadeOnZoom: true
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That markup and code works without issue for me in IE11. Are you using a web server to serve your page? Read the first paragraph here:  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/api_devenv.html

Answer (score 4):

It works in IE11. But if you access it as a file path like C:\projects\index.html then it will not load due to browser security. Not sure about exact details why.

Try the sandboxed sample in IE11
http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_simple

This worked because the page has loaded as a web URL

[image]

Suggest you to setup a web server like IIS, host your files in a virtual directory, and test the application.